# Title column of renderDataTable on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to separate my column name and arrows (which allow to change the column order)? Some of my name column are too long, so they glue arrows. 
[image: renderDataTable on shiny]

```
  output$resume <- renderDataTable({
    GetData()
  }, options = list(bSortClasses = TRUE, iDisplayLength = 10,
                    aLengthMenu = list(c(5, 10, -1), c('5', '10', 'All'),
                                       aoColumnDefs = list(list(sWidth=c("100px"), aTargets=list(0)))

                ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, separating the arrows from the column name doesn't seem to be possible as there's just no space, nor do I think it's possible. You haven't really given any breathing room to begin with.

My one suggestion/solution is to remove the sort arrows, if you don't need the feature of course.

```
output$myTable <- renderDataTable({
    myData()
  }, options = list(bSort=0))
```